# DVD Audio Playback Silent - how to find codec

Tags: sound, video, vlc, dvd, ffmpeg

I'm utterly baffled by this but I'm sure the fix must be simple - I can play DVDs fine on my ubuntu machine but I have just bought a new DVD and there is no sound.

The sound works on all other DVDs I've played and normal avi files also work, music works fine.  So I think it must be a coded missing but I have no idea how to narrow it down. Can someone help?

For reference I have libdvdcss2, libdvdnav4, restricted-extras installed.  I have tried vlc, mplayer and parole with no success.

Any help to determine the missing codec would be really appreciated.

Example mplayer output for working DVD:

> Playing dvd://.
>
> libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
>
> There are 39 titles on this DVD.
>
> There are 1 angles in this DVD title.
>
> libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
>
> libdvdread: This can take a *long* time, please be patient
>
> .....
>
> audio stream: 0 format: ac3 (stereo) language:  aid: 128.
>   number of audio channels on disk: 1.
>   number of subtitles on disk: 0
>
> Detected file format: MPEG-PS
>   VIDEO:  MPEG2  720x576  (aspect 3)  25.000 fps  7000.0 kbps (875.0 kbyte/s)
>
> ==========================================================================
>   Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
>
> Asking decoder to use 2 threads if supported.
>
> Selected video codec: [ffmpeg2] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-2)
>
> ==========================================================================
>
> ==========================================================================
>   Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
>
> AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 192.0 kbit/12.50% (ratio: 24000->192000)
>
> Selected audio codec: [ffac3] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AC-3)

>

> ==========================================================================

For the non-working DVD:

> Playing dvd://.
>   libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
>   There are 9 titles on this DVD.
>   There are 1 angles in this DVD title.
>
> libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
>   libdvdread: This can take a *long* time, please be patient
>
> libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x0000011f
>   libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
>   libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB at 0x0000015c
>   libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
>   libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB at 0x00000236
>   libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
>   libdvdread: Found 1 VTS's
>   libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
>   number of audio channels on disk: 0.
>   subtitle ( sid ): 0 language: en
>   subtitle ( sid ): 1 language: ja
>   number of subtitles on disk: 2
>
> Detected file format: MPEG-PS
>
> Too many video packets in the buffer: (4096 in 8256891 bytes).
>
> Maybe you are playing a non-interleaved stream/file or the codec failed?
>
> For AVI files, try to force non-interleaved mode with the -ni option.
>
> MPEG: No audio stream found -> no sound.
>
> VIDEO:  MPEG2  720x480  (aspect 3)  29.970 fps  9800.0 kbps (1225.0 kbyte/s)
>
> ==========================================================================
>   Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
>
> Asking decoder to use 2 threads if supported.
>
> Selected video codec: [ffmpeg2] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-2)
>
> ==========================================================================
>   Audio: no sound
>   Starting playback...

Answer (score 1):

Try install libdvdread4

> sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
>
> sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh

I believe that root cause of the issue is a region of DVD is not the same region of your DVD player. You can compare with another DVD which working on your ubuntu if it is a different region.

I used to change region ID of DVD player but it doesn't help. And I found that libdvdread4 help in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already have libdvdread4 installed so I don't think it is a region problem is it?

Comment: Have you checked the DVD region is it the same as your DVD player?